# res.json() creates CastError

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

When using res.json() with an argument it causes CastError:
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_id" for model "Post"

If I use just rest.status(),res.sendStatus() or res.json() without arguments it works without problem.

```js
exports.createPost = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    errorsIsEmpty(validationResult(req));
    const { communityId } = req.params;
    const { type } = req.query;
    const { title, content } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findById(req.userId)
    const community = await Community.findById(communityId);
    const banned = await community.authorized(req.userId)
    if(banned){
      ////// This line causes the problem //////
     return res.status(403).json({})
    }
    else {
      let post;
      if (type === 'text') {
      post = new Post({
        title,
        content,
        authorId: req.userId,
      });
    } else if (type === 'image') {
      if (!req.file) {
        const error = new Error('No image provided.');
        error.statusCode = 422;
        throw error;
      }
      const imageUrl = req.file.path;
      post = new Post({
        title,
        imageUrl,
        authorId: req.userId,
      });
    }
    await post.save();
  ////// This line works//////
    res.status(201).json({ postId: post._id });
    }
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    next(err);
    // errorFunc(err, next);
  }
};
```

r value "undefined" at path "_id" for model "Post"'

Comment: Could you show code for your Post schema ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `_id` is a string, but it needs to be an ObjectId type. I assume you're using mongoose. You need to import / require mongoose and then wrap the `_id` value in an `ObjectId`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

// in your route handler
  await post.save();
  ////// This line works//////
  res.status(201).json({ postId: ObjectId(post._id) });
```